# How to get Urine stains out of carpet

Tags: home, cleaning, pets, carpet

I recently got a puppy, and he is still not quite house trained. I attempt to clean up his accidents right away, but they still leave a small stain. I can see small circles on the carpet where he has urinated.

What is a good way to get the urine stains out of the carpet?

I haven't really used any methods yet, and I am too cheap for a carpet cleaner. I originally used vinegar to clean up the spots because i've heard it counteracts the urine smell. So short of vinegar, I haven't tried anything else.

Comment: Not trying to advertise here, but there is a product called Folex which is good at removing carpet stains: http://www.folexcompany.com/

Comment: There's a useful spot removal guide that I found a while back at https://www.aquamist.ca/spot-removal-guide/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Things I use:**

- Substitute Vinegar with Ammonia. Using ammonia requires vigorous rubbing and possibly a scrub brush, but if you clean 2 to 3 times with this method the smell goes. Also, try substituting with dish washing liquid, the good smell can help get rid of the odour and do some deep cleaning. Make sure you add water or a residue may build up.

  - Substituting with lemon juice works to, but can leave a stickyness unless you rinse with water or water down adequately.
- Mixing regular soap with baking soda helps with the odour and the mess.
- [Hydrogen Peroxide and water.](http://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Pet-Urine-from-Carpet#Using_Other_Remedies_sub)

> Start by dusting the stain with a thin coat of baking soda, then mix
>   up about a cup of hydrogen peroxide with a tablespoon of dish soap in
>   a spray bottle. Mix gently to combine. Then, saturate the baking soda
>   and the stain thoroughly. Use an old toothbrush or your fingers to
>   massage the mixture gently into the carpet, then let the mixture sit
>   until it dries. Vacuum up the mess and clean it again with cool
>   water.[3](http://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Pet-Urine-from-Carpet#Using_Other_Remedies_sub) Hydrogen peroxide can damage some kinds of carpet, making it
>   important that you spot test this mixture in an out-of-the-way area of
>   the carpet to make sure that it won't stain the carpet irreparably.

**Apply pressure with books or a container to help with moisture wicking. Wicking the urine up is the first step in all methods and know what will damage your floor. Wet and dry vacuums help with moisture control**

- Dogs like sniffing before they go know what your dog is allergic to and spray down some odours.

  - Vinegar
  - Essential oils- peppermint, anything minty, especially if it is strong.
  - Some perfumes, as they can have a burning smell.

    ---

**Additional Info:**

- [spotremoval.coit.com](http://spotremoval.coit.com/how-to-remove-urine-from-carpet):

> Before doing anything else, if the area is still wet, be sure to blot
>   the urine stain with a clean towel. You can also use paper towels to
>   help absorb any remaining urine. To prevent further absorption, the
>   faster you do this, the better. If you have access to any kind of
>   shop-vac, use it to extract any remaining urine. If you don’t have
>   this tool, proceed to the next step. Take one-quarter teaspoon of
>   liquid dishwashing detergent and mix it with one cup of warm water. Be
>   sure to specifically use this kind, not laundry detergent or dish
>   soap; these may contain bleach or lanolin.  If you have a spray
>   bottle, pour the solution into it. Spray the urine stain, aiming
>   directly onto the carpet. If you can extract the solution from the
>   carpet using a shop-vac, this is a good next step. Otherwise, you can
>   use a cotton cloth or paper towels after the solution has set into the
>   stain. After rinsing the area with warm water, repeat steps 1-5, as
>   long as you’re seeing the urine stain gradually fade. Last, take two
>   tablespoons of ammonia and mix into a cup of water. Rinse and repeat
>   until the stain has disappeared.

[Wikihow: How to Remove Pet Urine from Carpet](http://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Pet-Urine-from-Carpet#Using_Other_Remedies_sub)

[dogchatforums.com](http://www.dogchatforum.com/dog_urine_odor.htm)

[Homemade dog diapers?](http://pets.thenest.com/homemade-dog-diapers-4271.html)

Comment: Make sure to pick up as much urine with paper towels or a rag as possible while it's still fresh. Much of the time if this is done, only a little soap, a wet rag, and a fair bit of scrubbing will get rid of the smell

Comment: Ammonia is actually not good, because ammonia contains an ingredient that urine does, as such it "marks the spot" for a dog and causes future accidents.

Comment: Lemon juice works too

Answer (score 0):

If you tried what gentleman told and you are still not able to get the stain out of you carpet you can use bleach. If your carpet has a light color you won't see a big much differences but if it is dark don't use it. What you can do is.
Dilute one part of bleach with 8 part of water on a spray bottle. The bleach will pretty much eat the dye of you carpet and make lighter. If you hate the yellow stains and prefer to have a white stain instead. Go ahead and use bleach 1 to 8 dilution rate. Make sure to keep your pets out of the room until drys.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Nature's Miracle Stain and Odor Remover.  It removes odor and any stains from any surface.  I've used it through 2 dogs and a cat, works every time.

Answer (score 0):

Use baking soda and vinegar make a paste consistency and apply that to the stain with a clean rag or a scrub brush wait for it to dry and vacuum the spot and your done no smell no stain. This mix works well on most stains on the carpet even the ones that no matter what you do they just keep coming back.