# Cat Urine & Wood Floor

Tags: cleaning

I had a cat that urinated on the landing of my stairs a few years ago. I removed the carpet and wipe it down when I vacuum the steps. I am wondering if the vinegar and baking soda combo and then a product like [Kilz](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjD-JmQ2oTOAhXBNI8KHVIOD7kQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.homedepot.com%2Fp%2FKILZ-ORIGINAL-1-gal-White-Oil-Based-Interior-Primer-Sealer-and-Stain-Blocker-10901%2F100371321&bvm=bv.127521224,d.c2I&psig=AFQjCNHm7jLzKjFCS66pYsw9UpgpK8IjEg&ust=1469195560155731) will work? I want to re-carpet the landing.

Comment: Adult male, un-neutered? Get new floorboards. I have an antique guitar case that suffered the same fate... 30 years later & it still smells

Comment: Also take a look at [How to get cat urine smell out of wooden floors](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1861/how-to-get-cat-urine-smell-out-of-wooden-floors).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you a series of steps to follow in order to clean you stairs. I would recommend you to do this biweekly.

1. First of all, if you have a carpet at the landing, remove it and give it a clean wash.
2. Please ensure you put something like [this](https://p1.zopnow.com/images/products/320/comfort-comfort-fabric-conditioner-lily-fresh-800-ml.png) as after wash for a nice smell.
3. Now use [these](http://www.orangeglowoodcare.com/~/media/OrangeGlo/Home/Carousel/img_home_gloshelf.ashx?h=289&la=en&w=447) liquids to clean wooden floor.
4. After a good dry at sunlight, you can put back carpet on to the landing.

For a frequent result, you could use [these](http://www.regotrading.com/images/Airwickaero.jpg) to remove smell.

I am not having any tie up with above products or companies. Please do take them as examples and you can select appropriate substitutes if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Pet Smart has an enzyme spray that will break down the smell compounds. Not sure if it will damage the wood or not. I used it on painted wood and it didn't hurt the paint...

I successfully de-stank a room that had the same thing happen to it.

I also used a black light to see where the spots of pee remained, so I could really soak/scrub those areas with the spray.