# How to clean urine stain out of a bed mattress

Tags: cleaning, home, bedroom

My little child has a habit of moving to our bed during the night. Last night he wet our bed.

Some of the urine went though the sheets and reached the mattress. I tried to soak it with paper towels and wiped it with scented wipes, but there's still some urine smell left.

How can I get rid of that smell? It's a new mattress, so getting rid of it is not an option.

I found [this similar question about removing urine stains from carpets](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1857/how-to-get-urine-stains-out-of-carpet), but I don't know if the same cleaning methods can be applied safely on carpets and mattresses.

Comment: The Sun works wonders for removing the smell.

Comment: @Justin Well, that's interesting to learn, but it would be a challenge to try, since we are living in an apartment building and our position is such that we don't get much direct sunlight from our windows. We'll have to take the mattress downstairs and outside the building to get direct sunlight.

Comment: @Justin Actually I was wrong, my bedroom does get some direct sunlight from our south window, so I'll see if it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Febreze works well at removing all kinds of odors, for example hockey equipment, which tends to really reek after a sweaty session on the ice. There are specific types aimed at pet odor, such as urine stains on carpet, not expensive at all, especially compared to a new mattress.

If it's the visual stain that bothers you, maybe you could try an oxy cleaner. Or flip the mattress and forget about it for a while.

Fortunately, infants and small children don't have particularly strong smelling urine.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not sure if this brand is imported to Israel though. I don't remember seeing it here.

Comment: @Eran Apparently it's available (imported) but not cheap.

Answer (score 2):

Most HE laundry detergents also contain enzymes that would eliminate the stain and smell, but you would need to scrub repeatedly with plain water to remove the detergent (it can be irritating if left in the mattress).

You might use a pet stain remover, such as [this product at Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015HIN8PI), though you can probably find the equivalent at a local supermarket or pet store.

Answer (score 2):

[Nature's Miracle](http://www.natures-miracle.com/) and other pet stain removers work quite well at removing urine smells. It's an enzymatic cleaner that works best if you use it before you use any other cleaners. My sister used it on her car seat after her child had an accident in the car and it worked quite well.

[image]

Also, home carpet cleaning companies have access to professional chemicals and extractors that may do an even better job than common home products.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to check if we have something like that here.